# Can I use Right Alt/Ctrl Keys as Alt/Super/Hyper modifier keys of Emacs in Windows 10?

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows, modifier-key

I noticed that I've rarely used Right Control Key and Right Alt Key in my keyboard, so I'm wondering if I can use them as Alt/Super/Hyper modifier key in Emacs.

Is such a thing possible in Windows 10?

Taking a look at `w32fns.c' seems right control key is equivalently treated as left control key, so it may be difficult by Emacs alone.  I just want to know if it can be realized by the combination with AutoHotkey or other key event modifier tools.

BTW, assigning Windows (either Left/Right) Key as Super/Hyper key works perfectly in my environment by following codes, and I use Left Windows as functions provided by the Windows OS, so I only use Right Windows key as Superkey.

```
  (setq w32-pass-rwindow-to-system nil)
  (setq w32-rwindow-modifier 'super) 
  (w32-register-hot-key [s-])
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
RCtrl::F24
```

in Autohotkey Configuration,  then setting

```
(setq w32-pass-rwindow-to-system nil)
(setq w32-rwindow-modifier 'super) ; Right Windows key
(w32-register-hot-key [s-])
(setq w32-apps-modifier 'super) ; Microsoft Surface App Key
(bind-key "<f24>" 'event-apply-alt-modifier function-key-map)
```

in init.el solved most of my problems.

RCtrl key now acted as ALT modifier prefix key, and Right windows key act as Super Modifier Key.  (Except Win+G and Win+L, which are used by the Windows OS.)

Among Shift, Control, and Super modifier keys which are a supposed to be pressed by little fingers, only two can be pressed simultaneously.

Meta (Alt) modifier keys (left/right) are to be pressed by thumbs of both hands.

By pressing RCtrl (alt) key and then pressing Alt(Meta), Control and Windows Right (Super) key gives the event "A-C-M-s-x" key event in short period of time.